# run pde file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, processing, pde, processing-ide

What is the language of `.pde` file? Is it C or java? I want to run [these files of code](https://github.com/shiffman/The-Nature-of-Code-Examples/tree/master/chp07_CA/GameOfLifeWrapAround).

[This file](https://github.com/shiffman/The-Nature-of-Code-Examples/blob/master/chp07_CA/GameOfLifeWrapAround/GOL.pde) has an error because `width` and `height` variables are not initialized.

I want to know whether I run this code in Processing Development Environment if I have an error?

How can I run it in eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the language of .pde file? Is it C or java? I want to run these files of code.

A `.pde` file is a file that can be opened up by the Processing editor. It's written in the Processing language, which the Processing editor then compiles to Java to run.

You can download the Processing editor as a part of Processing from [here](https://processing.org/download/). That comes as a `.zip` file. Just unzip that anywhere, and then go into that directory and open up `processing.exe` (on Windows) to open up the Processing editor. From there you can open up a `.pde` file. This will also set up a file association, so double-clicking a `.pde` file will also open up the Processing editor.

You can also edit a `.pde` file as plain text (just open it in your favorite text editor), but you won't be able to run it without the Processing editor.

> This file has an error because width and height variables are not initialized.

Processing initializes the `width` and `height` variables for you.

> I want to know whether I run this code in Processing Development Environment if I have an error?

I would bet that if you run it inside the Processing editor, the error would go away. Of course, that's just a guess since you haven't told us specifically what the error is, but I do know that Processing initializes the `width` and `height` variables for you.

> How can I run it in eclipse?

You would create a project that uses Processing as a library, and then write code that executes the sketch. This has been covered on this site before. But I'd suggest just using the Processing editor until you have a better idea what you're doing.